# How can I need to pass the array in mutation as an input in QraphQL?

Tags: angular, rest, graphql, liferay, liferay-7

I have to use the mutation type of query in QraphQL.
I need to add a number of users in Liferay from my custom API. (Not using any of Liferay's out-of-the-box API.)

Then, How can I need to pass the array in mutation as an input in QraphQL?

My request body is something like that is

[
{
"UserName": "string",
"UserEmailId": "string"
},
{
"UserName": "string",
"UserEmailId": "string"
},
{
"UserName": "string",
"UserEmailId": "string"
},
]

Comment: Please [note the crossposting netiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)